# Junit testing- java.lang.AssertionError: Status Expected:<200> but was:<403>

Tags: spring-boot, api, junit5, mockmvc

I know this kind of questions has been asked before and I tried many of the answers given in there and none is doing good, So can someone please help me out in this for getting proper solution

Its my Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")

public class ABController {

    @PutMapping("/train/{trainId}/{status}")
    public ResponseEntity updateTrainstatus(@PathVariable String trainId, @PathVariable String status) {
        return feignClient.updateTrainstatus(trainId, status);
    }

}
```

Its my test controller class

```
private final String UPDATE_TRAIN_URI = "/admin/train?trainId=train100&status=approved";

@Test
public void testJsonController() throws Exception {
    String trainId = "train100";
    String status = "approved";
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(UPDATE_TRAIN_URI)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).characterEncoding("UTF-8");
    this.mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Train status"))
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your project has a configured spring security. Than the controller requires some authentication - for instance a jwt token in a request header. In test your request does not have a valid value than You receive a 403 forbidden status

Comment: what is the soultion for that ? how to add security in tyestcases

Comment: add this dependency:
```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```